# How do I trigger the change event on a react-select component with react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-select, react-hooks, react-testing-library

Given that I can't test internals directly with `react-testing-library`, how would I go about testing a component that uses `react-select`? For instance, if I have a conditional render based on the value of the `react-select`, which doesn't render a traditional `<select/>`, can I still trigger the change?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const options = [
  { value: "First", label: "First" },
  { value: "Second", label: "Second" },
  { value: "Third", label: "Third" },
];

function TestApp() {
  const [option, setOption] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="option-select">Select Option</label>
      <Select
        value={option}
        options={options}
        onChange={option => setOption(option)}
      />
      {option && <div>{option.label}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default TestApp;
```

I'm not even sure what I should query for. Is it the hidden input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following to get it working:

1. Fire focus event on the ReactSelect component .react-select input element.
2. Fire a mouseDown event on the .react-select__control element
3. Fire a click on the option element that you want to select

You can add a className and classNamePrefix props with the value of "react-select" in order to specifically select the component you are trying to test.

*PS: In case you are still stuck I'd encourage you to take a look at this conversation from where the above answer is borrowed - https://spectrum.chat/react-testing-library/general/testing-react-select~5857bb70-b3b9-41a7-9991-83f782377581*

Comment: I saw @gpx mention in that thread to mock it. I don't think I've ever mocked out a component. Does it work the same?

Comment: Thanks. I found [this one](https://spectrum.chat/react-testing-library/general/approaches-to-testing-components-that-use-react-select~85e86e37-9fdb-480f-8cba-217096414719) on spectrum too, which has an example test. .

Answer (score 32):

My team has a test utility in our project that lets us select an item easily after spending too much time trying to figure out how to do this properly. Sharing it here to hopefully help others.

This doesn't rely on any React Select internals or mocking but does require you to have set up a `<label>` which has a `for` linking to the React Select input. It uses the label to select a given choice value just like a user would on the real page.

```
const KEY_DOWN = 40

// Select an item from a React Select dropdown given a label and
// choice label you wish to pick.
export async function selectItem(
  container: HTMLElement,
  label: string,
  choice: string
): Promise<void> {
  // Focus and enable the dropdown of options.
  fireEvent.focus(getByLabelText(container, label))
  fireEvent.keyDown(getByLabelText(container, label), {
    keyCode: KEY_DOWN,
  })

  // Wait for the dropdown of options to be drawn.
  await findByText(container, choice)

  // Select the item we care about.
  fireEvent.click(getByText(container, choice))

  // Wait for your choice to be set as the input value.
  await findByDisplayValue(container, choice)
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
it('selects an item', async () => {
  const { container } = render(<MyComponent/>)

  await selectItem(container, 'My label', 'value')
})
```

Comment: This answer has been extracted into an npm package: https://github.com/romgain/react-select-event

Answer (score 0):

**Environment Setup** react-v18.2.0 react-select-v5.7.0

**Issue:** Click Event is not simulating and triggering **react-select** dropdown in order to automate the process.

**Solution:** You have to follow these steps in order to achieve this.

1. We will be using CSS selectors so in order to avoid any arbitrary classes, we have to configure the component.

```js
import Select from 'react-select';

<Select
    {...anyOtherConfig}
    id="countriesListDropdown"
    name="countriesList"
    instanceId="countriesList"
    inputId="countriesListInput"
    classNamePrefix='list'
/>
```

2. Now we will simulate the **mousedown** event on **dropdown Indicator**

   [triggerMouseEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025165/simulating-a-mousedown-click-mouseup-sequence-in-tampermonkey#answer-24026594)(document.querySelector("#countriesListDropdown .list__dropdown-indicator"), "**mousedown**");

   This will open the dropdown menu and list of items will be rendered in dom as well in div element.
3. Lastly we have to match the inner text of each div item and simulate **click event** on it, example:

```js
document.querySelector("#react-select-countriesList-option-1").click()
```

**Debugging:**
Once you run trigger step 2 event don't click anywhere on dom and just navigate from Elements Inspect, if you click anywhere on dom dropdown menu will hide itself.