# Select item inside a react-select dropdown list in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, dropdown, react-select

[Link example website here](https://react-select.com/home)

In that website, I am looking how to select item (e.g "Green") in "Single" dropdown box and "Grouped" dropdown box.

I tried to click to dropdown first and tried to find the element inside it to click but I can't

Do you have any idea? and with Grouped dropdown I even couldn't find the xpath to click on it

Thank in advance

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://react-select.com/home")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='select__value-container select__value-container--has-value css-1hwfws3']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@text()='Green']").click()
```

Comment: Great Q! In addition to the helpful responses below, I'd encourage you to look into [ActionChains](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) which can help you implement more "slippery" use cases...

Comment: @YaakovBressler: Your suggestion helped me solve the problem the code didn't work on the word "Silver". Thank you 


`dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='select__value-container select__value-container--has-value css-1hwfws3']").click()
option = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Silver']")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(option)
action.click(option)
action.perform()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove @ from text

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Green']").click()
```

To click on options that are not visible:

```
option=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Silver']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", option)
option.click()
```

You have to scroll first to that and then click

Comment: In case having another element "Silver" , I use driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Silver']").click() it just show the list and hightlight on "Silver" line but don't click (to choose)

Comment: @Scorpisces added answer for silver , you have to scroll to silver first

Comment: Ok your all solutions work well. But in action, my work didn't on main website (not example website) maybe I will ask in other question.
Thank you PDHide very much!

Answer (score 1):

To select **Green** from the *Single* dropdown box you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.get("https://react-select.com/home")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.basic-single > div.select__control > div.select__value-container"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'select__menu')]/div[contains(@class, 'select__menu-list')]//div[contains(@class, 'select__option') and text()='Green']"))).click()
```

- Browser Snapshot:

[image: ReactSelect]

Comment: It failed if I've changed to "Silver", they clicked on "Slate"

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to automate **react-select dropdown**, the reason was it renders the list once you click over it, but I will share the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54848370/how-do-i-trigger-the-change-event-on-a-react-select-component-with-react-testing#answer-76261558) that worked well with me, I will just give you an idea of how to achieve it because I used Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing my answer because none of the solutions I found worked for me. What I wanted was to select multiple values of of the select list:

- First I had to click on the react-select component for the list of options to appear.

```
react_select_button = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div..../div[1]')))
react_select_button.click()
```

- Then I clicked inside the input field and passed the 1st keyword option I wanted to search for and clicked on the rendered list.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='react-select-input']").send_keys("my-option-1")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "react-select-listbox"))).click()
```

- After that again since the mouse was on the input field I passed the 2nd keyword, clicked the list for the option to be selected.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='react-select-input']").send_keys("my-option-2")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "react-select-listbox"))).click()
```

- Finally, I hit the search button.

```
button_select = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/.../button[1]')))
button_select.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If any item is not able to be selected using custom selenium script than you can you can change zindex value to 9999 to be able to select it. After the click is completed than change it back to the original

private static String setZIndex(WebElement element, WebDriver driver, String desiredZIndex) {
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

```
    // Get the original z-index
    String originalZIndex = element.getCssValue("z-index");

    // Set the desired z-index value to bring the element to the front
    jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].style.zIndex = arguments[1];", element, desiredZIndex);

    // Return the original z-index value
    return originalZIndex;
}
```